# json chop my array's length

Tags: php, json, variadic-functions

I try to pass an array to json.   However, when the array has more than 96 elements, it automatically remove the rest elements.  no error message.  I don't know why?

For examples, if I define pids = new Array {'n0','01','n2',......'n95','n96'},  n96 is ignored.

Here is my code

```
var pids = [];
$('#moduleForm input[name="module[properties][]"]').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('checked') == true) pids.push($(this).val());
});

var formData = {
'module[properties][]':pids
};
```

Till the above step, module[properties] has all values.  n0 to n96.

```
var options = {
    url:'Module',
    data:formData,
    dataType:'json',
    timeout:60000,
    success:saveCallBack,
    error:ajaxError
};

$.ajax(options);
```

Is there a config setting somewhere I need to adjust?   I use php5.

---

Here is the data that is passed to json

status
    0

data
    Object { moduleId="1009", name="adsman", shortName="adsman", more...}

moduleId
    "1009"

name
    "adsman"

shortName
    "adsman"

isInternal
    "0"

status
    "1"

properties
    ["0", "1", "2", 93 more...]   **//  actually, it suppose to have 99 elements.**

error
    null

---

in php.ini  post_max_size = 9M

Thanks.

Comment: Here is the data that is passed to json:

status
 0
 

data
 Object { moduleId="1009", name="广告管理", shortName="adsman", more...}
 
moduleId
 "1009"
 
name
 "ad"
 
shortName
 "adsman"
 
isInternal
 "0"
 
status
 "1"
 
properties
 ["2", "3", "4", 93 more...]
 
error
 null

Comment: are you sure pids has 99 elements?

Comment: Yes. Pids has more than 96 elements.    If there are 96 elements, everything is good. As long as there are more than 96 elements, only the first 96 elements are passed to json.  I checked that pids and formdata are all correct.    I use firefox debug function to check json data, the field 'properties' can only hold maximum 96 elements.

Comment: Probably you hit the limit of the get request... try to add `type: 'post'` in the options.

Comment: Thanks. Meze.  But still the same problem.   Here is what I changed. 'var options = {
  url:'/admin/ModuleJson/do/getModule',
  data:'moduleId=' + moduleId,
  dataType:'json',
  timeout:60000,
  success:module_editing,
  error:ajaxError,
  type:'post'
 };'

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure this is not a JSON issue but instead you are probably POSTing more than your server will accept. Try increasing `post_max_size` in your php.ini. And possibly `upload_max_filesize`.

Comment: Default is 8M. That's one hell of a JSON string ;)

Comment: upload_max_filesize is 3M.    should be enough.   but still the same problem.